# How do I count how many times this vector changes from 1 to 2 for a certain condition?

Tags: r

This is an example of a part of my data:

```
S.T.R      Num.

S           1
R           2
T           1
S           2
S           3
S           1
T           1
S           2
S           1
R           2
```

I want to count the number of times that Num. changes from 1 to 2 and the S.T.R value that is assigned to that 1. So, the number of times that an S's 1 or a T's 1 led to a 2. Up until now I have been counting these happenings by hand but would like to find a way to do it in R.

Comment: hello robert please write down your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  filter(`Num.` == 1 & lead(`Num.` == 2)) %>%
  count(`S.T.R`)
dat2
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   S.T.R     n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 S         2
# 2 T         2
```

The total number would be `sum(dat2$n)`, which is 4.

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "S.T.R      Num.
S           1
R           2
T           1
S           2
S           3
S           1
T           1
S           2
S           1
R           2",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @RobertWeber Great! If both posts work. Please accept either mine or Andrew's post as the answer to your question. See this post to learn how to do it (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 1):

In base-R, if `df` is your dataframe, then define a column of the next values like this...

```
df$Next <- c(df$Num.[-1],NA)

df
   S.T.R Num. Next
1      S    1    2
2      R    2    1
3      T    1    2
4      S    2    3
5      S    3    1
6      S    1    1
7      T    1    2
8      S    2    1
9      S    1    2
10     R    2   NA
```

Then you can use the `table` function to cross tabulate `S.T.R` against `Next` for those rows for which `Num==1`...

```
table(df$S.T.R[df$Num.==1],df$Next[df$Num.==1])

    1 2
  S 1 2
  T 0 2
```

So there are two 1-2 transitions for each of S and T. You might want to ignore the `1` column, which is the count of those that stay as `1`.